# Could you cook a chicken in the oven if it was floating?

Tags: thermal-conductivity

Not sure if this is the correct place to put this question.

Suppose you put a chicken breast in the oven and somehow managed to get it to levitate, i.e. it wasn't in contact with anything.  Would the chicken still cook?  Or is part of the reason why chicken breasts cook because they're typically placed on something metal which has a huge thermal conductivity.  Air's thermal conductivity is much, much smaller than metal.  Even if you cooked the chicken on something which isn't metal, the grates in the oven on which that object would be placed are made of metal.

Comment: What does the oft-quoted advice that convention ovens will cook your food in one-third to one-quarter less time than conventional ovens tell you?

Comment: I never put my chicken on metal in the oven, I put it in ceramic trays. And they are insulting (not heat conducting at all).

Comment: Also, you can cook a garlic bread by putting it on the stones close to the fire on the camping trip. No heat conducting at all here. Instead: heat *radiation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a step back from your question, and ask yourself "why does the metal that the chicken is resting on get hot?" In an oven, it isn't in *direct* contact with the electrical heaters!

Unless the chicken is immersed in a liquid (and that type of cooking is not usually done in an oven, because the oven is not required to do it) almost all the heat transfer in an oven is by *radiation*, not conduction or convention.

Using radiative heating, the cooking would work just as well in a vacuum as in air, or with the chicken resting on a metal plate.

Comment: So the cooking in an oven has nothing to do with the particles surrounding the chicken?  It was my impression that heat transfer between the particles in the oven (be it the metal try or the air) and the chicken was mediated by the thermal conductivity of all of those materials.

Answer (score 0):

The thermal energy in the oven has the form of blackbody radiation. This radiation is a kind of "photon bath" that increases the chicken's temperature. Blackbody radiation from what I understand is just another way for a system to reach thermal equilibrium, in addition to heat conduction and transport.